# Extending a generic parameter in Typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I want to create a utility function which creates a checklist by adding an `isChecked` knockout observable property to each item in an array. This function should look like this:

```
createCheckList<T>(allEntities: T[], selected: T[]) : CheckListItem<T> {
    ...
}
```

I am returning a `CheckListItem<T>` because this interface should extend T to add the `isChecked` property. However, typescript will not allow me to do this:

```
interface CheckListItem<T> extends T {
    isChecked: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
}
```

Gives me the error:

> An interface may only extend another class or interface.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to express this in TypeScript.

You can obviously do this instead:

```
interface CheckListItem<T> {
    isChecked: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    item: T;
}
```

This has the advantage of not breaking the object when it happens to have its own `isChecked` property.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had considered that but it's rather clumsy IMHO. I've gone with returning an 'any[]' instead as I'm only using the results for knockout binding where type-safety doesn't buy me anything anyway.

Answer (score 7):

[Since TypeScript 1.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html) you can use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type CheckListItem<T> = T & {
  isChecked: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
};
```